# How to let CAS handle session

Tags: authentication-authorization

I am using the [phpCAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS)  library and would like sessions to be handled by that library.

I am instantiating the client this way:

```
function my_module_init(){
    ...
    phpCAS::client(CAS_VERSION_2_0,'casdomain' , 8443, '/cas',true);
    ...
}
```

I have it in hook_init() since I want to check for user authentication on each page load.

But I am getting this error.

> phpCAS error: phpCAS::client(): Another session was started before
>   phpcas. Either disable the session handling for phpcas in the client()
>   call or modify your application to leave session handling to phpcas

How can I get rid of this error and have phpCAS handle the session?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a copy of session.inc in your modules folder.  I named my mymodule.session.inc.
2. In mymodule.session.inc find the function drupal_session_initialize() and replace drupal_session_start() with the call to the of the CAS client constructor.
3. In your module's .install file set the location of mymodule.session.inc file

   function mymodule_install() {
             variable_set('session_inc', 'path/mymodule_session.inc');
       }

   function mymodule_uninstall() {
             variable_del('session_inc');
       }

As a result Drupal will create the CAS client before any session is created.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason why you are not using the module [cas](https://drupal.org/project/cas)? It seems like a fairly stable module with over 5000 people using it. I would give that a shot before attempting any custom code in hook_init().

Comment: That module does not handle Single Sign Out.  And it can't since that module does not manage the session which I am trying to do.

Comment: Surely it would be better to handle this as a patch to the module (and upstream it) versus rolling your own custom authentication module. Just think of the next guy to come across your code.

Comment: Looking at the code for 7.x-1.x-dev there is indeed code for hook_logout() to manage single sign out across CAS.

Comment: I stand corrected. That module does have code for single sign out.  Currently, I am having problem just logging in to CAS using that module.  Once I get things working I'll update this question.